# Blogger homepage won't update!

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

I am new on blogging webmaster tools. Usually, when I add new post to my blog, it will automatic update my homepage also. But from January 14th, my homepage doesn't update in the Google SERPs. As a result, I am losing my popularity in the SERPs. Previously when I posted new articles, 70-80% will go to the first page result. But after the problem occurs, none of them reach the top 15 pages of Google SERPs. :(

Last 1/12/12, Google webmaster sent me a "Notice of DMCA removal from Google Search" massage indicating one of my URLs contained some infringing content which I deleted after receiving their notice. Not only that, I also cheeked all of my posts if there any additional infringing content available.

After removing that, I filled out Google's content removed notification form to notify them. Google sent me a feedback that they received it and suggest "In the future, if you have removed the allegedly infringing content from your site (and won’t put it back), please  use the correct form" which also I filled in.

Now my question is:

1. Did I do all this right?
2. Although my new posts are indexed in Google with "..", why won't update my homepage which previously automatically updated when a new article was published?

Comment: When you say that your homepage isn't updated, is it your site itself that isn't showing new content on the homepage, or is it just Google that is no longer updating the index and search results with the new content of your homepage?  Please edit this question with this information, so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't know the answer and I can't find anything definitive online, but do take a look The [Electronic Frontier Foundation's DCMA guide for bloggers](https://www.eff.org/issues/bloggers/legal/liability/IP) and perhaps think about contacting them about the problem, they will have experience of dealing with this kind of thing.

Comment: thank you so much for the info...i'll contact with them..but will my site terminated? But if so, them why Google indexes my newly published posts? I'm also afraid :(

Comment: I don't think it's terminated, I think you've just fallen into a problem area by accident.